# how to show extract the cart total value and show in other pages?

Tags: php, dynamic, session-variables, shopping-cart

I have my session cart_array set, and showed the total inside variable $dynamicTotal all these code is in my cart.php ; and now I wanna retrieve this $dynamicTotal from my cart.php and echo out in my index.php how to I retrieve this specific value?? any hint would be great. Thanks

I have solved this the hard way..all i did is retrieve the minimal code required to calculate the cart_total and paste that code on top of all header of other page and echo out the value. Pasted code below for sharing.

I believe there is easy way to do it, eg, set the cartTotal to specific session variable then just retrieve that value from all the page which i failed to do so.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    /* Created by Adam Khoury @ www.developphp.com */
    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php";
   $cartTotal = "";
   $dynamicTotal= "";

    if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
       $dynamicTotal="empty";
    } else {
     // Start the For Each loop
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
            $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
            $sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1";
            $sql = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                $product_name = $row["product_name"];
                $price = $row["price"];
                $details = $row["details"];
            }
            $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
            $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;
            setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "ms_MY");
            $pricetotal = money_format("%10.2n", $pricetotal);
            $i++;
        }
        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "ms_MY");
        $cartTotal = money_format("%10.2n", $cartTotal);

        $dynamicTotal ="$cartTotal";
           }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved, posted my solution up which I think there's a much better way to do it